# how to convert the dictionary string to dictionary int?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, indexing

```
A = {'1': '[1,2]', '2': '[3,4]', '3': '[5,6]', '4': '[7,8]', '5': '[9,10]' }
B = {'1': '70', '2': '70', '3': '70', '4': '70', '5': '70' }
```

How to convert this multiple string dictionary into int dictionary?

Desired result :-

```
A = { 1:[1,2], 2:[2,3], 3:[3,4], 4:[4,5], 5:[5,6] }
B =  { 1:70, 2:70, 3:70, 4:70, 5:70 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string `[1, 2]` to list of `int` with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). For example:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

A = {"1": "[1,2]", "2": "[3,4]", "3": "[5,6]", "4": "[7,8]", "5": "[9,10]"}
B = {"1": "70", "2": "70", "3": "70", "4": "70", "5": "70"}


A = dict(tuple(map(literal_eval, i)) for i in A.items())
B = dict(tuple(map(literal_eval, i)) for i in B.items())

print(A)
print(B)
```

Prints:

```
{1: [1, 2], 2: [3, 4], 3: [5, 6], 4: [7, 8], 5: [9, 10]}
{1: 70, 2: 70, 3: 70, 4: 70, 5: 70}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without special library:

```
import json

A = {"1": "[1,2]", "2": "[3,4]", "3": "[5,6]", "4": "[7,8]", "5": "[9,10]"}
B = {"1": "70", "2": "70", "3": "70", "4": "70", "5": "70"}

A = {int(key): json.loads(val) for key, val in A.items()}
B = {int(key): json.loads(val) for key, val in B.items()}

print(A)
print(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
A = {'1': '[1,2]', '2': '[3,4]', '3': '[5,6]', '4': '[7,8]', '5': '[9,10]' }
new_dict = {}
for key, value in A.items():
    new_dict[int(key)] = eval(value)
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{1: [1, 2], 2: [3, 4], 3: [5, 6], 4: [7, 8], 5: [9, 10]}
```

Do the same thing for dictionary B.